# Limit access to subdirectory via specific SERVER_PORT using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to limit access to a specific subdomain via the server port, e.g. it can only be accessed from subdomain.domain.com:8443 and no other ports.

I'm currently using hostgator for my webhost, and it's already been setup such that subdomain.domain.com points to the correct subdirectory.

Now in the htaccess file, I'm currently trying this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subdomain
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8443$
RewriteRule   ^  -  [F]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As far as the blocking of other ports goes, it seems to work since accessing either subdomain.domain.com or www.domain.com/subdomain, I get a 403 forbidden page. But I can't get it to load the normal content correctly when I do access it via subdomain.domain.com:8443 or www.domain.com:8443/subdomain. Am I doing the rewrite conditions and rules correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `R=301` tells the server to do a redirect, not a (silent) rewrite. So, when you load via 8443, the user is redirected to `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/subdomain/$1` without the port 8443 specification and they are then blocked by the first rule. If you do a `curl -I` on subdomain.domain.com:8443 you should see the 301 redirect code rather than 200.

Remove the R=301 and remove the full domain specification in the final RewriteRule to leave:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]`

This should do a silent rewrite of the content.